# Asking a reference for a fact about nonlocal operators

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, fourier-analysis, elliptic-pde, pseudo-differential-operators, micro-local-analysis

Let assume that $u$ is smooth enough and $ -\Delta (u \phi) \in L^1(\Omega)$ for any $\phi \in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$. Then it easily follows that $ -\Delta u \in L^1_{\mathrm{loc}}(\Omega)$ by considering
$$ \Delta (u \phi) = u \Delta \phi + 2 \nabla u \cdot \nabla \phi + \phi \Delta u. $$

I want kindly to ask is there a reference for the corresponding fact for the fractional Laplacian case, i.e. $ (-\Delta)^{s} (u \phi) \in L^1(\Omega)$, $0<s<1$, for any $\phi \in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$, then $ (-\Delta)^{s} u \in L^1_{\mathrm{loc}}(\Omega)$.

Thanks.

Comment: A comment to the first sentence: note that if $u$ is "smooth enough", then $\Delta u$ is continuous, so it is obviously locally integrable. Regarding your question: if $u$ is not locally integrable in the neighbourhood of $\partial \Omega$ (or if $(1+|x|)^{-n-2s}u(x)$ is not integrable at inifnity), then $(-\Delta)^s u$ is not even well-defined, at least — not in the usual sense.